# Mapping other collection by same schema name on Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, mongoose

Engine Collection

```
var EngineSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,
    GF2: String,
    GF3: String,
    GF4: String,
    ll98: String,
    ll01: String,
    ll04: String

});
```

Oil Collection

```
var OilSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,
    GF2: String,
    GF3: String,
    GF4: String,
    ll98: String,
    ll01: String,
    ll04: String

});
```

I made simple

Engine DB

{ _id: 57d9604b7ecbc0029a3aad3c,
  name: 'N54 B30A',
  ll01: '1',
  ll01fe: '1',
  ll04: '1',
  __v: 0 }

OilDB

[ { _id: 57d9614265e6c402a2c09990, name: 'EDGE', ll04: '1', __v: 0 },

{ _id: 57d98e12acc05505cfd15aae,
    name: 'SYNTEC',
    GF2: '1',
    GF3: '1',
    GF4: '1',
    __v: 0 } ]

If I have the N54 B30A than It needs classification about ll98, ll01, ll04

EDGE Product only one about classification ll04

totally I choose the 'N54 B30A' that has ll04 classification so I want to appear something that has the ll04 classification

'N54 B30A' -> ll04 
'EDGE' -> ll04

ll04 mapping?

Select N54 B30A -> appear EDGE

My Code Simple but It did't execute

```
Engine.findOne({name: 'N54 B30A'}, {_id: 0, name: 0, __v: 0}, function(err, engine) {
    var result = Object.keys(engine.toObject());//[ 'll01', 'll01fe', 'll04' ]
    Oil.findOne({result[2] : 1},function (err, oil) {
        console.log(oil)
    });
})
```

More Question 
I want to search many kind atrribute(ll01, ll01fe, ll04) such as

```
findOne({$or:{ll01:1},{ll01le:1},{ll04:1}},function...)
```

but I don't know how to add one item like {ll01 : 1} than add {ll01le:1} and {ll04:1}
I tried coding

My Code

```
Engine.findOne({name: 'N54 B30A'}, {_id: 0, name: 0, __v: 0}, function (err, engine) {
    var result = Object.keys(engine.toObject());//[ 'll01', 'll01fe', 'll04' ]
    var Json = [];

    result.forEach(function (item) {
    var code = {};
    code[item] =1;
        Json.push(code);

    });
    console.log(Json);


    Oil.find({$or: Json}, function (err, oil) {
        console.log(oil)
    });
})
```

I'm not useful javascript so I made by only my thinking. is this right?

Comment: Could you describe the requirement in more detail. Unable to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: ok right. I wrote detail.

Comment: Was my answer helpful??If so please upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a value to JSON as `{result[2] : 1}`. Change your code to this

```
Engine.findOne({name: 'N54 B30A'}, {_id: 0, name: 0, __v: 0}, function(err, engine) {
    var result = Object.keys(engine.toObject());//[ 'll01', 'll01fe', 'll04' ]
    var oilFindQuery = {};
    oilFindQuery[result[2]] = 1;

    //or query 
    var orQuery = [];
    result.forEach(function (item) {
        var queryItem = {};
        queryItem[item] = 1
        orQuery.push(queryItem);
    });

    //oilFindQuery = {$or: orQuery};

    Oil.findOne(oilFindQuery, function (err, oil) {
        console.log(oil)
    });
})
```

Comment: Could I ask one more question?  If I want to make the query that find({$or:{ll01:1},{ll04:1}}). I tried "oilFindQuery[result[0]] =1", oilFindQuery[result[2]] =1 but It make be {ll01:1,ll04:1} I want to search ll01 : 1 product and ll04: 1product

Comment: If you want to do and `AND` query then `{ll01:1,ll04:1}` will work fine, but with an `OR` query you will have to change the way the query is formed

Comment: so I made the code I'm not useful javascript so could you check the my code?  is that right? "var result = Object.keys(engine.toObject());//[ 'll01', 'll01fe', 'll04' ]
    var Json = [];

    result.forEach(function (item) {
        var code = {};
        code[item] =1;
        Json.push(code);

    });"

Comment: Could you modify the above question or create a new question. Its very difficult to infer the change in comments

Comment: sorry for the late response, was busy over the weekend